# Python package install

Tags: package

Packages
How can I install packages in a code editor,is there any other way other than pip install.
I have visual studio code and pycharm, also cv2 package is not working does it have any way to install

Comment: are you working on Windows or MacOS, on a local machine or deplying on a web server?
VSCode has its own packages tool, you can find many Python packages up there.

Comment: Windows 10 professional

Answer (score 1):

You have Pycharm, right? Read the documentation of Pycharm for installing, uninstalling, and upgrading packages using GUI [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html).

Comment: Happy to help. Happy to receive a vote too! JK.

Seriously, most often, there's a GUI version for every decent IDE out there. Even Anaconda has one.